# Is Dajjal Big or short?

Tags: dajjal

One time i heard that Dajjal shall be a short person but in another story he was described as a very big creation. Is there a difference in oppinion?

Answer (score 5):

The hadith describing the Dajjal as short appears in Sunan Abi Dawud:

> Narrated Ubadah ibn as-Samit:
>
> The Prophet (ﷺ) said: I have told you so much about the Dajjal (Antichrist) that I am afraid you may not understand. The Antichrist is short, hen-toed, woolly-haired, one-eyed, an eye-sightless, and neither protruding nor deep-seated. If you are confused about him, know that your Lord is not one-eyed. ([Sunan Abi Dawud 4320](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:4320))

This hadith has been weakened by some scholars, and Al-Albani has considered it Sahih.

As for the hadith describing Dajjal as a "big" creation, it appears in Sahih Muslim:

> Hisham ibn Amir said:
>
> I heard Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) as saying: There would be no creation bigger than the Dajjal right from the creation of Adam to the Last Hour. ([Sahih Muslim 2946a](https://sunnah.com/muslim:2946a))

And another narration of the same hadith has the wording:

> أَمْرٌ أَكْبَرُ مِنَ الدَّجَّالِ ‏
>
> "No issue bigger than Dajjal." ([Sahih Muslim 2946b](https://sunnah.com/muslim:2946b))

This sheds some light on what this hadith means by the word "bigger."

Imam Nawawi in his explanation of Sahih Muslim commented:

> قَوْلُهُ ﷺ (ما بَيْنَ خَلْقِ آدَمَ إلى قِيامِ السّاعَةِ خَلْقٌ أكبر مِنَ الدَّجّالِ) المُرادُ أكْبَرُ فِتْنَةً وأعْظَمُ شَوْكَةً
>
> The Prophet (SAW)'s statement ⟪There would be no creation bigger than the Dajjal right from the creation of Adam to the Last Hour⟫ means bigger in trial and greater in infliction.
>
> ([Sharh An-Nawawi 18/86](https://app.turath.io/book/1711?page=4008))

Qadi Iyad comments:

> وقوله:»ما بين خلق آدم إلى قيام الساعة خلق أكبر من الدجال «: تفسيره الحديث الذى بعده وفيه:»أمر أكبر من الدجال " فهو كبر الشأن وعظم الفتنة، لا كبر الجسم، هذا الأظهر. وقد يحتمل أنه يشير إلى عظم الجسم.
>
> His statement ⟪There would be no creation bigger than the Dajjal right from the creation of Adam to the Last Hour⟫ is explained in the hadith right after it ⟪No issue bigger than Dajjal⟫, so it is the size of the affliction and greatness of the trial, not size of body. This is the most apparent. But, it is possible to say it points to greatness of the body. ([Ikmaal al-Mu'allim 8/504](https://app.turath.io/book/122406?page=4937))

So, although someone can possibly claim this hadith refers to size, it can be seen that the apparent meaning of Dajjal being a "big creation" refers to the trial and test he represents. There is no trial bigger than the Dajjal even though he might be in physical appearance short.